# explain alfresco config evaluator="xx" condition="yy"

Tags: workflow, share, alfresco, activiti

I am trying **alfresco 4.2c**.

I am struggling with learning alfresco customization.
can someone explain what this xml tag does:

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="yy">
 ...
 ...
</config>
```

Is the condition part checking a config file that has a setting yy?
which config file is that and where can it be found?

There are also other**s**  
which I also need to understand. Sorry if this is too basic, but I cant move on to read and understand other **alfresco** documentations without first understanding this.

I most likely missed the docs that explain these, can someone more knowledgeable direct me to some relevant docs explaining these, please. (I have been jumping from one doc to another without really understanding these.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration evaluators are used in Alfresco to override and customize the user interface simply modifying xml files.

As reported [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140805041007-45133456--techtip-custom-evaluators-for-alfresco-s-form-config)

> In this file, an evaluator element 
>   is used to target the elements for customization. These evaluators are
>   managed by the SpringSurfXmlConfigService. This service is extended by
>   the Alfresco web client framework to include the following default
>   evaluators:
>
> - string-compare defined by [StringEvaluator](http://swazzy.com/docs/springsurf/da/d31/a00678.php)
> - node-type defined by [NodeTypeEvaluator](http://swazzy.com/docs/alfresco/d2/dce/classorg_1_1alfresco_1_1web_1_1config_1_1forms_1_1_node_type_evaluator.php)
> - task-type defined by [TaskTypeEvaluator](http://swazzy.com/docs/alfresco/d2/d8f/classorg_1_1alfresco_1_1web_1_1config_1_1forms_1_1_task_type_evaluator.php)
> - aspect defined by [AspectEvaluator](http://swazzy.com/docs/alfresco/d8/d31/classorg_1_1alfresco_1_1web_1_1config_1_1forms_1_1_aspect_evaluator.php)
> - object-type defined by [ObjectTypeEvaluator](http://swazzy.com/docs/springsurf/de/df8/a00440.php)

Almost all configuration files ending with the suffix "`-config.xml`" contain configuation sections like the one you mentioned.

> The configuration service uses an amalgamation approach. An object is
>   given as the context and a lookup is performed to retrieve all the
>   configuration that matches that object.
>
> There are several built-in evaluators that can be used i.e.
>   'string-compare' and 'object-type'. Other custom evaluators can be
>   plugged in by specifying them at the top of the config file (see
>   example below). All configured evaluators are called and passed the
>   context object. If the evaluator matches that section of config is
>   added to the result.
>
> All sections that match are merged into one result, this allows a fine
>   grained configuration approach, and also allows overriding of
>   configuration data. However, this does mean that configuration is
>   sensitive to the order things are defined in the file, basically, the
>   last item wins.
>
> This 'lookup' algorithm, however, can also be customized and plugged
>   in when a config lookup is performed.

This means that as long as the application context is loaded, many objects are registered and you'll be able to add/modify configuration of these objects setting in the `condition` attribute the object you want to modify.

For example, if you look to your `web-client-config-custom.xml` file, you will see that there is a Language section containing the languages to be shown on the login page.
If you want to add more languages to the list, all you have to do is to add an entry to this list:

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Languages">
    <languages>
        <language locale="ca_ES">Catalan</language>
        <language locale="hr_HR">Croatian</language>
        <language locale="cs_CZ">Czech</language>
    </languages>
</config>
```

Starting from the `application-context.xml` file you will find that it includes more specific `*-context.xml` files, leading to `the web-client-config.xml` file that contains the  `<element-reader element-name="languages" class="org.alfresco.web.config.LanguagesElementReader" />` to read the languages section.

More examples can be found in the [Web Client Customisation Guide](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Client_Customisation_Guide)

In general you should take a look to official Alfresco documentation and, even if this [Config Service wiki post](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Config_Service) is a bit outdated, it may help you understand the mechanism that didn't change so much even in newer versions.

Comment: sorry, i was hoping to provide a longer comment.  will do as suggested.

Comment: I used the "Languages" example becuase it's one of the simplest which you can customize. In fact it is used only in web-client-config.xml. To override the default behaviour you should edit a web-client-config-custom.xml containing your changes and put it into ALFRESCO_HOME\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\extension. This is possible exploiting the convention over configuration concept brought in by Spring. And yes, the last configuration loaded is the winner.

Comment: i still cant get these:
1. The config service uses an amalgamation approach. An object is given as the context and a lookup is performed to retrieve all the configuration that matches that object.
2. All configured evaluators are called and passed the context object. If the evaluator matches that section of config is added to the result.
3. the syntax

  ... condition="Languages">  
  <languages>  
     <language locale="es_ES">Spanish</language>  
  </languages>  

confuses me (upper and lowercase languages).

is condition referring to a <Languages> section 
that has been previously loaded?

Comment: this is how i am 'understanding' it:
the application-context.xml is the main config file, it calls all the other .xml config files.
there are a lot of these but one (or more, but the last one wins?) contains a section, say

<Languages>  
    English    
    German  
</Languages>   
(i just assumed above, i can't find the .xml with Languages section except in web-client-config.xml)

Comment: so if i write z-context.xml and import it as the last config xml,  
then i can override whatever is in <Languages> above with: 

#z-context.xml
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Languages" replace=true>
  <languages>
     <language locale="nl_NL">Dutch</language>
     <language locale="ru_RU">Russian</language>
  </languages>
</config>  
?
once again, thanks.